# Changing the activity dashlet

Tags: search

CiviCRM 4.5.6. (trouble updating at this time)
Drupal 7.34

I am just beginning to explore customizing CiviCRM. I have a lot of questions. Any answers to the following question will give me a better foundation upon which to explore my other questions.

On the dashboard, the activity dashlet shows the date but not the time of day.

What php or template file do I change to make the time part show? The time does show when I do a search for activities.

Also, what do I change to make the time the first column in the report?

I have spent hours studying the documentation but failed to make some kind of connection between that information and my needs.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

[image: Activity Dashlet showing area without time]

Answer (score 1):

An excellent question - the Advanced Date Settings don't seem to affect the report.

You can try to make it a type of "timestamp" in civiroot/CRM/Report/Form/Activity.php.  You might also want to build your report in Views. If you choose this approach, you'll want to install [the Drupal Views in CiviCRM Dashlets module](https://civicrm.org/blogs/brandonferrell/drupal-views-civicrm-dashlets)

Comment: Thanks Jon. A follow up question:

By Views you mean within Drupal? Or is there a Views feature in CiviCRM?

Comment: Views within Drupal - there is excellent CiviCRM integration with Views out of the box to use Civi data in Views.  Also, I edited my answer above to show how to display Views on the dashboard. Super powerful!